# "This may get confused" or "This may get confusing"

Tags: past-participles, present-participles

This morning I was talking to a friend and I came out with the sentence:

"This picture may get confused" with the meaning "This picture is so strange that you could get confused" then I started thinking that, maybe, I could have said "This picture may get confusing". Is There any difference between

"This may get confused" and
"This may get confusing"?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a big difference. A picture that confuses the viewer is confusing, with the result that the viewer is confused. A confused picture would be one which itself lacked coherence.

Answer (score 0):

> This may get confusing.

or even better

> This may become confusing.